# picamera Python module: How to simultaneously capture H264 video to file and live stream

Tags: python, video, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to capture a H264 video file and a live video stream accessible via HTTP or RTP, using Python and the `picamera` module.

Currently, the example I am using is http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask ,however it works only for JPG.

Is there a similar approach for using HTTP connection and live streaming of H264 video?